# Get specific item from Repeater in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForms project that displays data read from a database via a Repeater. The code for the repeater looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repRMAproduct" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
               <td>
                    <%# Eval("Description") %>
               </td>
               <td>
                    <%#  Eval("Qty") %>
               </td>
               <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbNewQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
          </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I want is for the user to enter a new Quantity only on the rows that he wants to enter. Then, when he clicks the save button, I can read these new Quantities along with their associated Descriptions.

In MVC I should build the URL using jQuery and pass it to the Controller. But in WebForms it seems less intuitive. Where do I go from here?

Comment: How do you determine what value was modified? If the textbox is not empty or it's value is `!= Eval("Qty")`?

Comment: Unmodifide values will have a tbNewQty that is empty. Again, if I was building a URL in jQuery I could check this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your save-button-click event handler you can loop all items and get the `TextBox` with `FindControl`:

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repRMAproduct.Items)
{
    TextBox tbNewQty = (TextBox) item.FindControl("tbNewQty");
    string newQuantity = tbNewQty.Text.Trim();
    int quantity;
    if(int.TryParse(newQuantity, out quantity))
    {
        SaveNewRmaQuantity(product, quantity);
    };
}
```

If you'd use a `Label` for your product-description you can use `FindControl("LblDescriptionId")` to get it and to pass it's `Text` to `SaveNewRmaQuantity`. You can also use invisible controls(`Visible=false)`, f.e. a `Label`, to store the `ProductId`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code and whilst it compiles it tells me that the ItemRepeater ("repRMAproduct") contains no items, even though I know it does by looking at the front end. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside a click event. Should I call it elsewhere?

Comment: @MSOACC: i guess that you DataBind the repeater on every postback, for example in `Page_Load`. Use `if(! IsPostBack){ DataBindRepeater(); }`. Otherwise, without more code it's difficult to find the reason for the issue.

Comment: I do Databind on every PostBack. Why is that an issue?

Comment: @MSOACC: because all changes in the repeater are lost, it will be recreated with the database values. Also, no events of the repeater or controls in it will be triggered. It's not needed anyway with enabled ViewState.